# Sometime w is based on pixel density, sometime no, others it just breaks

Tags: html, responsive-design

Here is the HTML code I wrote:

```
<img src="Images/small.jpg"
 srcset="Images/small.jpg 200w,
         Images/large.jpg">
```

So, I want small.jpg to be used up to a 200 wide screen and then I want large.jpg to be used instead.
Problem is, in the developers tools, with cache disabled and refreshing the page each time this code doesn't work with a 1x pixel density, with 2x and 3x it works fine, respecting the 200px limit no matter the density.

And if I use 3 images, for example:

```
<img src="Images/small.jpg"
 srcset="Images/small.jpg 200w,
         Images/large.jpg 400w,
         Images/huge.jpg 800w">
```

Depending on the pixel density now, it could display an image with a smaller size.

Please, don't reply suggesting some CSS code, I'm trying to figure out srcset and sizes one step at the time, I'd rarther focus on that

P.s. I can't find anything online on the W unit

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing this?

To work out how the `200w`/`400w`/`800w` is interacting you can use Chrome.

Right-click your page, click "inspect", then click the phone/tablet icon (in blue in the screenshot below):

[image]

Then in the centre, at the top menu you can change the device you are 'impersonating':

[image]

Your code works.

This is demonstrable by switching between `iPhone 5/SE` and `Laptop with HiDPI screen` (or `Pixel 2`).

The way the `w` unit works is like this:

The browser iterates through your image source-set then does a calculation.

For the purposes of this lets assume the device you are on is 450px wide, and is a 1x display (not retina)...

The browser will calculate:

```
200/450 = 0.44...

400/450 = 0.88...

800/450 = 1.77...
```

Since you're using a 1x non-retina display, the closest is 400w (400/450) and thus it will load the large jpeg as it is closest to 1 (1x display -> 1.0).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use the developers tools in Chrome and switching between iPhone 5/SE and Laptop with HiDPI screen doesn't change anything (even refreshing the page and disabling cache), it just loads huge.jpg.  So, concerning w, that's the calculation? Then why on other code no matter the pixel density it respects always the same sizes??

Comment: Does it react differently depending on the pixel density? How does that even work?